# Adding manifest information to a Visual C++ project

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, manifest

I'm writing a C++ program that has to run as administrator. I gather the way to arrange this is to add a note to that effect to a manifest file that will be linked into the executable. How do you do this?

In C# you can create a manifest with Add New Item, but that doesn't seem to apply to C++.

Project Properties/Linker has a section on manifests, but this seems to discuss automatically generating a manifest each time the program is compiled, rather than generating a manifest once that can be then edited. However, even though Generate Manifest has a value of Yes, no manifest file appears in the project directory tree after a build.

What am I missing?

Comment: The manifest is normally auto-generated in a C++ project.  The entry you want to change is directly exposed as a project setting: Linker > Manifest File > UAC Execution Level.  Why it "doesn't work" is completely invisible, you need to do a better job documenting your problem.  Certainly starting by mentioning the VS version you use.

Comment: Also, IMO, this setting in C++ project is more simpler than a CS project.

Comment: I would have been happy if I would have found a solution to generally add an individual manifest into a c++ compiled program (and the Administrator-Priviledge thing as an example to that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Project -> Properties
2. Linker -> Manifest File
3. UAC Execution Level : **requireAdministrator**

[image]

NOTE: The manifest will be embedded into EXE file itself, as a resource. You don't need to edit it.

Comment: Ajay what if you want to run your C++ project from Visual Studio in debug mode but need the admin privilege. When I attempt to run my C++ project from Visual Studio I get - HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED) : The requested operation requires elevation. on the statement: pServer.CreateInstance(CLSID_SSServer);  (COM Server)? Do I need to create an external manifest file for this project? Is that the best way?

Comment: @NealDavis Why not set the UAC execution level of the project you're debugging with `requireAdministrator` administrator as mentioned above? You need to double check the project and configuration you're setting this property. 
If setting is correct, and if VS itself is not running elevated, it will promptly prompt to restart VS with elevation.
If you are trying to debug running application, or a DLL, then you need another approach